# Getting zipcode from facebook with java

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, street-address, restfb

I am using the Facebook rest api restfb and java. Is it possible to get a user's address info? Presently I use com.restfb.types.User, but I can't seem to get the address data with that. I am able to get other data such as name, gender, and email. But not address.

My research led me to this site (http://code.google.com/p/restfb/source/browse/trunk/RestFB/library/src/main/java/com/restfb/types/User.java?r=323) but I am not sure what I am supposed to do with the code. If I copy the code and use it will I suddenly be able to get user address data from Facebook (I haven't gone that route yet because it would require a lot of changes to test it)?

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 2):

You can query such user information from Facebook if:

- Your application requests permission to access the user's information via one of their authorization APIs (they have JavaScript and OAuth versions)
- The user then approves your application, thereby giving you the permission you
  need to query the data

Please see https://developers.facebook.com/ for detailed information.

Comment: I have done so and do have access to the user data. I can get things like first name, last name, email, etc. But there is no method for getting address in the restfb api that I am using.